# Slidedown header elements one by one with sequential delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to get slide down 4 headings consequently one by one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( function() {
                $( "#h1" ).slideDown( 2000 );
                $( "#h2" ).delay( 2000 ).slideDown();
                $( "#h3" ).delay( 2000 ).slideDown();
                $( "#h4" ).delay( 2000 ).slideDown();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <h1 id="h1" style="display: none;">First line</h1>
            <h2 id="h2" style="display: none;">Second line</h2>
            <h3 id="h3" style="display: none;">Third line</h3>
            <h4 id="h4" style="display: none;">Fourth line</h4>
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

What I've seen:

1st animation: H1 slides. Ok.

2nd animation. H2, H3, H4 slides together. Wrong - I expect to get: 2nd animation with H2, 3rd animation with H3 and 4th animation with H4.

So, how to make this animation sequence doing right?

Comment: Stagger the delays, `.delay(2000)`, `.delay(4000)` etc. or place the `slideDown()` within the callback of the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) loop function with [header selector](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector) to work with all headers:

```
$(':header').each(function(i,v){
  $(this).delay(i*2000).slideDown();
});
```

Or, if you wanted only specific headers, then select:

```
$('#h1,#h2,#h3,#h4').each(function(i,v){
```

Comment: Or he can add same class on each element and use that instead of ids.

Comment: Or, `$('.headersDiv :header')`

Comment: This is most elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to achieve the result:

Update the delay since animation queue is independent of elements.

```
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000);
  $("#h2").delay(2000).slideDown(2000);
  $("#h3").delay(4000).slideDown(2000);
  $("#h4").delay(6000).slideDown(2000);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000);
  $("#h2").delay(2000).slideDown(2000);
  $("#h3").delay(4000).slideDown(2000);
  $("#h4").delay(6000).slideDown(2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="h1" style="display: none;">First line</h1>
  <h2 id="h2" style="display: none;">Second line</h2>
  <h3 id="h3" style="display: none;">Third line</h3>
  <h4 id="h4" style="display: none;">Fourth line</h4>
</div>
```

---

Or move the code to the animation [complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) to execute after the animation complete.

```
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000, function() {
    $("#h2").slideDown(2000, function() {
      $("#h3").slideDown(2000, function() {
        $("#h4").slideDown(2000);
      });
    })
  })
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000, function() {
    $("#h2").slideDown(2000, function() {
      $("#h3").slideDown(2000, function() {
        $("#h4").slideDown(2000);
      });
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="h1" style="display: none;">First line</h1>
  <h2 id="h2" style="display: none;">Second line</h2>
  <h3 id="h3" style="display: none;">Third line</h3>
  <h4 id="h4" style="display: none;">Fourth line</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the number of seconds:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000);
  $("#h2").delay(3000).slideDown();
  $("#h3").delay(4000).slideDown();
  $("#h4").delay(5000).slideDown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="h1" style="display: none;">First line</h1>
  <h2 id="h2" style="display: none;">Second line</h2>
  <h3 id="h3" style="display: none;">Third line</h3>
  <h4 id="h4" style="display: none;">Fourth line</h4>
</div>
```

Or use the next animations as callbacks:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#h1").slideDown(2000, function() {
    $("#h2").slideDown(2000, function() {
      $("#h3").slideDown(2000, function() {
        $("#h4").slideDown(2000);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1 id="h1" style="display: none;">First line</h1>
  <h2 id="h2" style="display: none;">Second line</h2>
  <h3 id="h3" style="display: none;">Third line</h3>
  <h4 id="h4" style="display: none;">Fourth line</h4>
</div>
```